# What is the best method for estimating average channel fidelity?

Tags: quantum-operation, fidelity, state-tomography, quantum-process-tomography

[This thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0512217.pdf) shows an efficient way to estimate average channel fidelity (in chapter 4). However, it is somewhat old (from 2005). Are there any better methods out there? By *better* I mean: are there other methods that can achieve the same accuracy of estimation but with fewer qubits? (or put another way, are there methods that can achieve higher accuracy with the same amount of qubits)

I imagine some methods for fidelity estimation and/or quantum tomography of single qubits could be used to modify and improve the method from the thesis I cited. If so, does anyone specifically know which methods could be used, and how? Thanks!