# What is the best quantum process tomography method?

Tags: quantum-operation, fidelity, state-tomography, quantum-process-tomography

This question is somewhat related to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17252/what-is-the-best-method-for-estimating-average-channel-fidelity). What is currently the best method for quantum process tomography? By *best* I mean, the one that can achieve the best accuracy of estimation per qubit used.

Comment: a relevant discussion is found in (Mohseni et al. 2008, [quant-ph/0702131](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702131))